# How can I insert the tag use the .html() from ajax success?

Tags: jquery, html

I use the ajax and after success if data.length more than less 200, I want some tag html change.

`$('#...').html()` is normal but `$('#...').html("...");` is not a working.

Can I get help to find my mistake?

I'm sorry I'm not good at English.

```
<!-- html code -->
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 200px;" /><!-- 별점 -->
        <col style="width: 300px;" /><!-- 제목 -->
        <col style="width: auto;" /><!-- 내용 -->
    </colgroup>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="txt_center">추천별점</th>
        <th class="txt_center">제목</th>
        <th class="txt_center">내용</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody id="review_list">
    </tbody>
</table>



<!-- script code -->

$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "/search/get_goods_review",
    data : {"location":location},
    success: function(data) {
        $('#review_list').html(data);
        if($('#review_list').html().length < 200){
            $('#review_list').html("<tr><td colspan='5' style='text-align:center;'>리뷰 정보가 없습니다.</td></tr>");
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, stat, err) {
        alert("실패");
    }
});
```

Comment: Easy and quick to test if `$("#..").html("..")` is working for you by commenting all the ajax code except `$('#review_list').html("<tr><td...` - you'll see there's no problem there.   It's most likely the response `data` is not what you're expecting it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to change like below (changes are commented):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "/search/get_goods_review",
    data : {"location":location},
    success: function(response) { //always use different names to remove ambiguity
        if(response.length < 200){ //check response.length less that 200
            $('#review_list').html('<tr><td colspan="5" style="text-align:center;">리뷰 정보가 없습니다.</td></tr>'); //yes then replace HTML
        }else{
            $('#review_list').html(response); //otherwise paste coming response
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, stat, err) {
        alert("실패");
    }
});
```

Comment: @유효림  glad to help you :)